# Android app sends pictures to web server and pictures rotate

Tags: android, html, image, web-applications, webserver

I am making an android app that sends pictures the user explicitly took and send it to a web server. Next, i display those pictures in a web application.

However, the pictures taken from the smartphone in portrait appear in the server rotated as if they were taken in landscape mode and vice versa.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14066265/2345913

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231552/uploading-image-on-server-receiving-rotated-image try this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a property of the image, "exif tag". Which tells about the orientation of the image. You can check the value of this tag before sending the image to server.

you can use below method to get the unrotated image

```
public final static Bitmap getUnRotatedImage(String imahePath, Bitmap rotattedBitmap)
    {
        int rotate = 0;
        try
        {
            File imageFile = new File(imahePath);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation)
            {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotate);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(rotattedBitmap, 0, 0, rotattedBitmap.getWidth(), rotattedBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);
    }
```

It takes two arguments, image path and the bitmap image.

Try this method before sending the images to the server.