# Upload image from phone with orientation

Tags: php, android, mysql, file-upload, image-uploading

When I upload image with my phone to my website, it save and display it in landscape mode(bigger width), even if I take the picture in portrait mode(bigger height). But when I upload it from my PC all works well. Have you heard of this problem, and any solutions to solve it?

PS.I don't think I need to add the code, because its just a simple adding image to the folder.

This is how I save the image in the folder:

```
move_uploaded_file($name,"../../main/".$user."/Post/".$path);
```

Comment: what are you using to upload the image? when using a library it is possible that it is modifying it for upload, sometimes changing the file format changes the orientation of the image. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308921/fix-ios-picture-orientation-after-upload-php So you need to be more specific with the uploading process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP read\_exif\_data and Adjust Orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489742/php-read-exif-data-and-adjust-orientation)