# Safari renders rotated image

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Does anyone experience weird issue where safari is rendering rotated image?

Our tech stack is in laravel for the backend and reactjs from the front end. I thought it was a matter of front end rendering. However clicking at the link straightaway to the image in safari opens up the image as a rotated image.

How do you handle this? I tried to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308921/fix-ios-picture-orientation-after-upload-php) issue and another one from [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/rotate-images-from-ios) but the image was uploaded using chrome and it is a png image.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

[image: Safari rendered]

[image: Chrome Rendered]

Comment: have you checked the the EXIF of the image? the orientation might be set to X degrees

Comment: Yeah its not rotated. The orientation's fine, it is rendered fine in both in chrome and firefox. Uploaded with the correct orientation but its just retrieved differently in safari