# Image is rotating when sending only in multipart post request to the backend server

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, multipartform-data, image-rotation

I am making a post request using multipart form-data. with the following code I can able to send the image but when I go the backend server and check, the  image that I sent is rotating there . anyone have idea why it is happening ?

```
NSURL *reqUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:self.dataModel.apiUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:reqUrl];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSDictionary *requestBody = self.dataModel.requestParams2;
UIImage *imageToUpload = [requestBody objectForKey:keyUploadImage];
    if(requestBody){
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
          float low_bound = 0;
    float high_bound =5000;
    float rndValue = (((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*(high_bound-low_bound)+low_bound);//image1
    int intRndValue = (int)(rndValue + 0.5);
    NSString *str_image1 = [@(intRndValue) stringValue];


    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 0);
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile1\"; filename=\"%@.jpeg\"\n",str_image1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
}
   [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
   [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)

 {
              NSLog(@"completionHandler with response:%@",[NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]]);
     NSLog(@"reponse: %ld",(long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]);

     NSInteger status = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode];

     if(error){
         NSLog(@"http request error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
         // handle the error
     }
     else{
         if (status == 200){
             // handle the success
         }
         else{
             NSLog(@"error");
         }   // handle the error
     }


     }];
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAMJy.png ---This is the image in the server

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NGSK.png --- This is the actual image that I want

Comment: @AndreasOetjen please read my question clearly, here I am sending in post request using multipart but not using image picker controller. And it is going properly for normal post request only in case of multipart image is rotating

Comment: I read this, but I assume that the original JPEG image is rotated somehow. JPEG stores the image orientation in EXIF metadata, but PNG does not. To test, you could just store the PNG to the local file system and see if it's also rotated "wrongly". Or, just send the PNG and not the JPEG to the server.

Comment: I backend server  accepts only jpeg format what to do for that and the same jpeg image data is going correctly in post request

Comment: Maybe I misread it. Nevertheless, you should check the orientation flag in the exif data both of font- and backend

Comment: but how can you comment as duplicate without reading it properly ??strange

Comment: @AndreasOetjen??

Comment: sorry for that, I removed the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the image rotation is happening when I crop the image then I used  this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14231694/7636194 after cropping then my issue is got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove orientation data from UIImage before uploading to the server.

```
UIImage *originalImage = [requestBody objectForKey:keyUploadImage];

UIImage *imageToUpload =
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]
                    scale:[originalImage scale]
              orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
```

You should use imageToUpload to upload to the server.

Comment: Could you just somehow send a link to both the original and the server image?

Comment: my image orientation is already in up but it gets rotated after upload and this happening only when I crop the image

Comment: crop? Where do you crop the image, I cannot see it in your code.

Comment: crop that I am doing before this

Comment: That's exactly what I told you at the very beginning. And you are not using jpeg but png format, which doesn't support image orientation.

Comment: I am using jpeg only

Comment: The images you uploaded on imgur are png images; it could be helpful to see the images in jpeg format, exactly as they were sent to and received by the server

Comment: there I just added screenshots to show the rotation

Comment: Unfortunately, screenshots are no help at all; I would need the orginal (cropped) jpeg image (`imageToUpload`) and the image that's stored on the server.